# Is there any optimization package in J like optim in R?

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, j

In J is there a package similar to optim in R?

Comment: Software recommendations are off-topic, perhaps you should try on [softwarerecs.se], but make sure to check their question requirements first because you will need to provide more information about your specific needs